# Using the facebook c# sdk in asp.net without a canvas application

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Im trying to use the sdk without a canvas application, so have followed steps 1-7 in the quickstart guide up to adding the facebookSettings property in the Web.config.

I have added an image to my page and an onclick event that contains the below code. but when I click the button, it just takes me to the home page (CancelUrlPath).

Changing the Authorizer to a CanvasAuthorizer results in FB loading the login screen, but I get an error 404 not found on the call (even after inserting the handlers into the config)..

```
fbApp = new FacebookApp();

authorizer = new Authorizer(fbApp) {Perms = requiredAppPermissions};
authorizer.ReturnUrlPath = "http://localhost/User/UserRegister.aspx";
authorizer.CancelUrlPath = "http://localhost/";
if (authorizer.Authorize(this.Context))
{
  Response.Write("hello");//never gets here
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Note: I've set the canvas and site url to http://localhost/ on the FB app settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just building a simple connect website you really don't want to use the server side authentication tools to authenticate your user. Just use the Javascript SDK to athenticate the user. If you need to do anything on the server side, the FacebookApp class will automatically pick up the user's session from the values stored in the cookies.

See the Facebook documentation for more details: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#registration